# write down the proposition corresponding to p→ q and determine the values of x for which it is false

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Need an explanation for the below discrete mathematics problem's solution

Problem :
write down the proposition corresponding to p → q  and determine the values of x for which it is false, where

p: x+y = xy where x, y ∈ R

q: x ≮ 0 for every x ∈ Z

Solution:

p → q is the statement ' if x+y = xy for x, y ∈ R then x ≮ 0 for every x ∈ Z '

In this case , q is false . Therefore , the conditional statement will be true if p is false also, and it will be false for those values of x and y that make p true.

So p → q is false for all those real numbers x of the form  y/(y-1), where 
y∈ R{1}. This is because if x= y/(y-1) for some y ∈ R`\`{1} , then x+y = xy,
ie, p will be true.

Here is my question :

I could understand that p : x+y = xy will be true for value  like 2, but I don't understand what does R`\`{1} mean?  the term y∈ R`\`{1}, what does this mean ? Are they coming to say for value 1 also , proposition p is true?  what Please explain

Comment: $y \in \mathbb R \setminus \{ 1 \}$ means that $y$ is a *real* number different from $1$.

Comment: Got it nw, if y is 1 then x will become infinity,  thank you for the explanation   Mauro ALLEGRANZA